# Rendering the Face Normals with Eevee as they are displayed in the Viewport overlay

Tags: texturing, normals, shader-nodes

Is there possibly a way to render the face normals in Eevee as they are displayed in the viewport?

I have two simple shapes here as an example. These use a simple *Checker* texture.

[image]

In the viewport, I can now enable the *Face Orientation* option in the overlays:

[image]

This additionally displays the normals of the faces in red and blue mixed with the underlying texture:

[image]

Is there any way to reconstruct this effect with Eevee so that I essentially get in the rendered image the result that the overlay in the viewport creates for me?

**Note:** I'm looking for a way to solve this with a material, because this effect should not be applied to the whole scene, but only to a specific object with a specific material!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having encoded back and front facing with red and blue:

[image]

It looks as if it could be a simple *Add* to the original texture, as above .. but I have to confess to having trouble getting an exact match:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly for my use case, because I don't need an exact reproduction of the effect, but only an additional coloring of the materials, caused by the orientation of the faces!